# How to free up memory from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, memory-management, out-of-memory, ienumerable

I'm making a program that prints out all Nodes in a Collatz tree in C#.
This takes up a whole lot of memory, and outOfMemoryExceptions have been the word of the day. The base of the program is as follows:

```
        var fileStream = File.Create("collatz.txt"); //just print into a textfile for testing
        var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

        IEnumerable<Node> nodeList = new List<Node>()
        {
            new Node(1, null) //rootNode
        };
        Task flushTask = Task.CompletedTask;
        while (nodeList.Any())
        {
            var tempList = CalcChildren(nodeList); //Return a IEnumerable of children of all the parents in the nodeList
            await flushTask;
            foreach (var node in tempList)
                writer.WriteLine($"{node.Value} -> {node.Parent.Value}: {node.StepsFromRoot}");
            flushTask = writer.FlushAsync();
            nodeList = tempList;
        }

        writer.Close();

    static IEnumerable<Node> CalcChildren(IEnumerable<Node> parents)
    {
        foreach(var parent in parents)
            foreach (var child in CalcChildren(parent))
                yield return child;
    }

    static IEnumerable<Node> CalcChildren(Node parent)
    {
        var multiValue = parent.CalcMultiplicationValue();
        if (multiValue.HasValue)
        {
            var child = new Node(multiValue.Value, parent);
            parent.MultiplicationChild = child;
            yield return child;
        }
        var divValue = parent.CalcDivisionValue();
        if (divValue.HasValue && divValue.Value!=1)
        {
            var child = new Node(divValue.Value, parent);
            parent.DivisionChild = child;
            yield return child;
        }
    }
```

I think herein lies the problem but for the sake of completeness, the Node class:

```
    public class Node
{
    public Node(int value, Node parent)
    {
        Value = value;
        Parent = parent;
        if (parent != null)
            StepsFromRoot = parent.StepsFromRoot+1;
        else
            StepsFromRoot = 0;
    }

    public int Value { get; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    public Node DivisionChild { get; set; }

    public Node MultiplicationChild { get; set; }

    public int StepsFromRoot { get; set;  }

    public int? CalcMultiplicationValue()
    {
        if(Value<=int.MaxValue/2)
            return 2 * Value;
        return null;
    }

    public int? CalcDivisionValue()
    {
        double newValue = (Value - 1) / 3.0;
        if (newValue % 2 == 1 && newValue >= 1)
            return (int)newValue;
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm trying my best to drop as much memory as possible, but it doesn't seem to work. Around the 105th iteration this program takes up 4 GB of memory! I first thought it was because the buffer of my writer was taking up all the memory. Now I think it's because the collection of nodes isn't cleaned up by the garbage collector.

I tried to make it more minimal. But I'm not sure what to delete while keeping it complete. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the issue at our end.

Comment: Each nodes have reference to it's child and parent so you always have the whole tree loaded up in memory. It shouldn't increase in size as they are all pointers. But, that being said, reassigning or creating new `List` creates new array each time. This is pretty slow, you should either use a recursive method (might be as worst) or walk the whole tree once to get all nodes in a single level list then iterate that list once.

Comment: @mjwills Tried to do it. Might be a bit bulky now, but it's complete.

Comment: @Franck Edit because I completely misread your comment. You're completely right that might be the problem!

Comment: [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JweTBY) a working example of a flatten in action. It doesn't run on fiddle but in a visual studio for real it works.